# Not receiving the Firebase Authentication OTP in android app

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication

I am new to android development, I was creating a login method in android studio in kotlin using firebase but after inputting the mobile number the screen just loads and no otp is recieved and the app is stuck in the login activity and the other activity where I have to add to add the otp is not working.

loginactivity.kt

```
class LoginActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var loginactivitybinding: ActivityLoginBinding
    val auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
    lateinit var callbacks: PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks
    var codesent = ""

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        loginactivitybinding = ActivityLoginBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        val view = loginactivitybinding.root
        setContentView(view)



        //Checks whether the phone number we entered is correctly entered or not --->
        loginactivitybinding.sendotp.setOnClickListener{
            val userNumber = loginactivitybinding.phoneEdit.text.toString()
            callbacks = object: PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks(){
                override fun onVerificationCompleted(p0: PhoneAuthCredential) {
                    loginactivitybinding.progressbarlogin.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                    loginactivitybinding.sendotp.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                }

                override fun onVerificationFailed(p0: FirebaseException) {
                    loginactivitybinding.progressbarlogin.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                    loginactivitybinding.sendotp.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                }

                override fun onCodeSent(otp: String, p1: PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken) {
                    loginactivitybinding.progressbarlogin.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                    loginactivitybinding.sendotp.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    val intent = Intent(this@LoginActivity, OTPVerificationActivity::class.java)
                    intent.putExtra("Number", userNumber)
                    intent.putExtra("code",otp)
                    startActivity(intent)
                    finish()
                }
            }
            if(!userNumber.isEmpty()){
                if(userNumber.length == 10){
                    loginactivitybinding.sendotp.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                    loginactivitybinding.progressbarlogin.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    val options = PhoneAuthOptions.newBuilder(auth)
                        .setPhoneNumber(userNumber)
                        .setTimeout(60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                        .setActivity(this@LoginActivity)
                        .setCallbacks(callbacks)
                        .build()
                    PhoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(options)
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"Enter a valid Number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"Enter a Mobile Number First", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }


    }
}
```

otpverificationactivity.kt

```
class OTPVerificationActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var otpverificationBinding: ActivityOtpverificationBinding
    var verificationCode = ""
    var userNum = ""
    lateinit var callbacks: PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks
    val auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        otpverificationBinding = ActivityOtpverificationBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        val view = otpverificationBinding.root
        setContentView(view)



        verificationCode = intent!!.getStringExtra("code").toString()
        userNum = intent!!.getStringExtra("Number").toString()

        otpverificationBinding.verify.setOnClickListener {
            if(!otpverificationBinding.otp1.text.toString().isEmpty() && !otpverificationBinding.otp1.text.toString().isEmpty() && !otpverificationBinding.otp1.text.toString().isEmpty() && !otpverificationBinding.otp3.text.toString().isEmpty() && !otpverificationBinding.otp4.text.toString().isEmpty() && !otpverificationBinding.otp5.text.toString().isEmpty() && !otpverificationBinding.otp6.text.toString().isEmpty()){
                var userInput = otpverificationBinding.otp1.text.toString()+
                        otpverificationBinding.otp2.text.toString()+
                        otpverificationBinding.otp3.text.toString()+
                        otpverificationBinding.otp4.text.toString()+
                        otpverificationBinding.otp5.text.toString()+
                        otpverificationBinding.otp6.text.toString()
                if(verificationCode != null){
                    otpverificationBinding.progressbarotp.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    otpverificationBinding.verify.visibility = View.INVISIBLE

                    val credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(verificationCode,userInput)
                    signInWithCredential(credential)
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Please Check your connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
                //Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"Verified",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"Please Enter all the numbers",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
        otpblockmove()

        otpverificationBinding.resend.setOnClickListener {
            callbacks = object: PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks(){
                override fun onVerificationCompleted(p0: PhoneAuthCredential) {

                }

                override fun onVerificationFailed(p0: FirebaseException) {

                }

                override fun onCodeSent(otp: String, p1: PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken) {
                    verificationCode = otp
                }
            }
            val options = PhoneAuthOptions.newBuilder(auth)
            .setPhoneNumber(userNum)
            .setTimeout(60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .setActivity(this@OTPVerificationActivity)
            .setCallbacks(callbacks)
            .build()
            PhoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(options) }
    }

    // Function to move the otp block by 1 place
    private fun otpblockmove() {
        val otpFields = arrayOf(
            otpverificationBinding.otp1,
            otpverificationBinding.otp2,
            otpverificationBinding.otp3,
            otpverificationBinding.otp4,
            otpverificationBinding.otp5,
            otpverificationBinding.otp6
        )
        for (i in 0..4) {
            otpFields[i].addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
                override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {
                    // Not needed, but must be overridden
                }

                override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
                    // Automatically move to the next OTP field when a character is entered
                    if (!s.toString().isEmpty()) {
                        otpFields[i+1].requestFocus()
                    }
                }

                override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
                    // Not needed, but must be overridden
                }
            })
        }

    }

    fun signInWithCredential(credential: PhoneAuthCredential){
        auth.signInWithCredential(credential).addOnCompleteListener { task ->
            if(task.isSuccessful){
                otpverificationBinding.progressbarotp.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                otpverificationBinding.verify.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                val intent = Intent(this@OTPVerificationActivity, MainActivity::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)
                finish()
            }else{
                otpverificationBinding.progressbarotp.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                otpverificationBinding.verify.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"Error",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Make sure you have updated the SHA 1 In Firebase console and your Google service.json is updated. if all is updated please let us know more detail as you are trying in emulator? or you are getting any error in logcat

Comment: Thanks for the reply but after doing some changes like using the intent method after the phone auth options it now works

Comment: "is not working" doesn't provide enough information so we can help. What exactly doesn't work? Do you have any errors? Please respond using @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo I meant that it is not sending the otp and even the otp verification activity is not opening when i enter the number,